# Attempting to speed mysql queries on large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am hitting some performance issues on a Mysql server.

I am trying to query a large table (~500k rows) for a subset of data:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `subset_id` = id_value;
```

This request takes ~80ms to achieve, but I am trying to query it over 20k "id_value", which makes the total execution time of almost 1h.
I was hopping that adding an index on `subset_id` would help, but it's not changing anything (understanding how indexes work, it makes sense).

What I am trying to figure out is if there is any way to "index" the table in a way it wouldn't take 80ms to execute this query but something more reasonable?
Or in other work, is ~80ms for querying a 500k rows table "normal"?

Note: On the larger picture, I am using parallel queries and multiple connections to speed up the process, and tried various optimizations changing the innodb_buffer size. I'm also considering using a larger object querying the db once for the 500k rows instead of 20k*xx but having my code designed in a multiprocessed/co-routines/scalable way, I was trying to avoid this and focusing on optimizing the query/mysql server at the lowest level.

Thanks!

Comment: As a note, adding "ORDER BY subset_id" seems to speed up the query by 4x

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @jchevali how is that relevant?

Comment: You be the judge of what's relevant. It's your thread.

Comment: @jchevali I am genuinely wondering what made you think of early optimizations

Comment: Your last paragraph, which is screaming to the world that you don't need any help.

Comment: @tbronchain - More likely, the `ORDER BY` had no impact; instead it was a caching issue.

Comment: @tbronchain - Multiple connections, multiple individual queries, etc -- these are costly.  Gordon's answer will be much simpler _and_ better.

Comment: @tbronchain - It should not take 80ms for a simple, indexed query.  Unless...  it returns lots of rows; the server is most of 80ms distant from the client; you have lots of big text columns; (and maybe some other issues).  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the table size, whether there is network latency, etc.

Comment: "I was hopping that adding an index on subset_id would help, but it's not changing anything (understanding how indexes work, it makes sense)." -- How? It must help with good cardinality! Have you force mysql to analyze table? Have you checked explain plans before and after adding the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single query with `IN` rather than a zillion queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `subset_id` IN (id1, id2, . . .);
```

If your ids are already in a table -- or you can put them in one -- then use a table instead.  You can still use `IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `subset_id` IN (SELECT id FROM idtable);
```

Comment: Would also suggest not to use select *, but to include columns explicitly

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion and even though not exactly answering my question this is how I think it is going to be implemented eventually.

Comment: @Gauravsa thanks for the suggestion, but doesn't seem to improve performances

Comment: Don't use the `IN ( SELECT ... )`; use a `JOIN` instead.

Comment: Sometimes it can make things worse as simple queries with single id would be cached while more complicated queries with list of random IN(ids) will not be cached (no repeating queries with the same ids, result too bit etc). I do not know exact situation to be sure.